# AD Query into .txt file to remove line in .csv of existing users

Tags: powershell

I am using a piece of code here that uses a Master.txt file with a list of usernames, it queries Active Directory and checks if they are a user or not. Afterwards it populates two seperate .txt files called UserExists and UserDoesntExist.

```
$Users = Get-Content "Desktop\Master.txt"
ForEach ($User in $Users)
{
    $UserObj = $(try {Get-ADUser $User} catch {$Null})
    If ($UserObj -ne $Null)
    {
       Write-Host "$User Exists" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Yellow
       Add-Content 'Desktop\UserExists.txt' "$User"
    }
    else
    {
       Write-Host "$User Doesn't Exist" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow
       Add-Content 'Desktop\UserDoesntExist.txt' "$User"
     }
}
```

The two lists work fine as expected, there is also a .csv file that contains every user on the master.txt file but with headers in for Password etc and other fields for user creation further down the line. But I'd like to remove the line in the.csv where the user already exists based on a .txt file. Is there a way to read the .txt document of UserExists and then look up the matching Username in the .csv and remove the line? This is a field in both the .csv and .txt file so it would match. Is this doable? Any help and advice would be really appreiciated.

Comment: You should do the filtering of the Csv at runtime (while querying AD, all put together) instead of when the filtering is complete. What attribute of the AD user matches with the column on the Csv? (samAccountName / distinguishedName / etc) and what's the name of the column ?

Comment: Hi Santiago. The matching attribute is the samAccountName it is the same in both the .txt document and the .csv so thats the identifier. I've just never had anything setup where I can delete out of the CSV file. The column is called Username

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it, hopefully the inline comments helps you get the logic:

```
$Users = Get-Content "Desktop\Master.txt"
# import the csv
$Csv = Import-Csv "Path\To\Csv.csv"

$output = ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    # if the user could be found this condition and assignment holds `$true`
    If ($UserObj = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(samAccountName=$User)") {
        # output this user's `SamAccountName` (which is captured in `$output`)
        $UserObj.SamAccountName
        Write-Host "$User Exists" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Add-Content 'Desktop\UserExists.txt' "$User"
        # go to next user
        continue
    }
    Write-Host "$User Doesn't Exist" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Add-Content 'Desktop\UserDoesntExist.txt' "$User"
}

# filter the Csv where the `Username` column is not in the `$output` array
$csv.Where{ $_.Username -notin $output } |
    # and export the filtered Csv
    Export-Csv "path\to\filteredCsv.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Santiago! This works absoloutely perfect and has solved a few headaches. I was just wondering as the script errors when the user isn't found. Is there a way to catch the error rather than the red text? Thank you so much

Comment: Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'TA999999' under: 'Domain'

Comment: @DanielDeLaWarr are you sure `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` is there in your code?

Comment: It is, it only appears to do it when it can't find a user in AD. But when it does find the user then it works fine with no error :)

Comment: @DanielDeLaWarr ok with that update shouldn't see more errors